# Create a script for editing file in specific line in Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I am a beginner, working in government. I want to create a form so that I can edit and delete data in certain rows on certain sheets in Google Sheets, which would be very useful to support my work. Can friends here tell me what the script is and the steps for the script app? Thank You.

I have tried this script, but failed.

```
function update_database(){
    var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");
      var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
        var brs_akhir = s2.getLastRow();
        var brs_data = s2.getRange("G"+brs_akhir).getValue();

      var NAMA = s2.getRange("B"+brs_akhir).getValue();
      var NIP = s2.getRange("C"+brs_akhir).getValue();
      var PG = s2.getRange("D"+brs_akhir).getValue();
      var JABATAN = s2.getRange("E"+brs_akhir).getValue();
      var UNIT = s2.getRange("F"+brs_akhir).getValue();

    if (NAMA !== "" ) {
        s1.getrange("B"+brs_data).setvalue(NAMA);
    }

    if (NIP !== "" ) {
         s1.getrange("C"+brs_data).setvalue(NIP);
    }

    if (PG !== "" ) {
         s1.getrange("D"+brs_data).setvalue(PG);
    }

    if (JABATAN !== "" ) {
         s1.getrange("E"+brs_data).setvalue(JABATAN);
    }

    if (UNIT !== "" ) {
      s1.getrange("F"+brs_data).setvalue(UNIT);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `a form so that I can edit and delete data in certain rows on certain sheets in Google Sheets` and your showing script. Can I ask you about the details of your current issue and your expected result? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Perhaps because `s1.getrange("B"+brs_data).setvalue(NAMA);` should be `s1.getRange("B"+brs_data).setValue(NAMA);`.  Same for others.

Comment: Thank you for your answers and attention, I have now found the script from a tutorial on YouTube. I also got the script above from a tutorial on YouTube. Also sorry if my English is not good, and I'm still really unfamiliar with scripts, this is just because of work requirements in my office.